How to iterate over grep -R output in busybox?
I would like to collect comments in a bunch of files which start with # into files which only contain the comments. I can do it this way:
find . -type f -exec grep '^#'  {} > /path/to/comment/storage/{}
Very simple. This, however, is incredibly wasteful as it forks a grep for every file and creates a lot of empty files too. grep -R '^#' . would be much better but what do I do with the output of it? Something like export IFS=:;grep -R '^#' .|while read -r file contents; do echo $file-$contents; done is a promising start however this falls apart when the contents themselves also contain colons. It also has the challenge of properly creating and appending to each file.
As an additional restriction, this need to run with busybox as shell / awk / etc, GNU utils are not available.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

? it affects whether your proposed answer will work - certainly someone else trying to use your code on a non-flat hierarchy will encounter problems. and stackoverflow is intended to be helpful to more than just the person asking the question. it also affects whether I suggest ways to fix the problem

At the very least, you can use find ... -exec grep '^#' {} + to reduce the number of grep processes to execute. find will pass as many file names as it can to grep each time it invokes it. If you use -l, every line will be guaranteed to start with a file name, making it easier to strip the file names (at least, if you assume no file name itself contains :).

OP: read -r file contents does work for contents containing colons, it is only your subsequent echo $contents unquoted that fails; something like printf '%s\n' "$contents" >"$file" should work (though I agree awk is better) @chepner: you mean -H; -l prints only the filenames that contain a match but not the matched content

@dave_thompson_085 Argh, right. I wanted to stick with POSIX-only options, but misread the description of -l and confused it with -H.

As I write this it appears your input has no subdirectories, or that the ouput directory hierarchy has already been created. If that is the case, you can do:
find . -type f -exec awk '
        FNR==1 {
            if (NR>FNR) close(out)
            out = "/path/to/comments/" FILENAME
        }
        /^#/ { print >out }
    ' {} +


awk's print >file truncates file before first write and thereafter appends until close(file)

note that there is a potential gotcha in this code: if one wished to test for non-existence of something rather than existence as here, then there is an ambiguity about whether empty input files should be ignored or result in creation of corresponding empty output files. The way the code above behaves, if testing instead for non-comments (say by !/^#/) empty input files will be ignored.

This will fork an awk process for every file. How is this better than forking a grep for every file?

@chx no, it won't. using + as exec terminator is not the same as using \;. Multiple invocations of awk may still occur if there are a large number of files, but the resulting code is much simpler and so is likely to be easier to maintain

Got it. One more question: why if (NR > FNR) instead of if (NR > 1) ?

@chx the test may actually not be needed at all since close("") doesn't fail. It's mostly a style issue - 1 is a magic number and the intent should be clearer with NR>FNR (which I believe is the idiomatic way to test "not the first file")

@EdMorton for brevity (or if one has remembered that it's safe to close something that isn't "open"...), definitely. As pedagogy or if the actions needed on file change became more complicated (if (NR>FNR) { ... }) then having it there flags up that ... is not intended to happen until the second file

I was unaware awk supported printing to a file by itself without shell redirects, this answer showed me and the man page confirms

print expr-list >file Print  expressions  on  file.   Each expression is separated by the value of OFS.  The output record is terminated with the value of ORS.

Although the manpage is of GNU Awk this seems to work with busybox awk as well.
Second, we already have an answer on how to print everything except the first field with awk.
So we can do
grep -R '^#' . | \
awk -v FS=: -v OFS=: '{ key = $1; $1 = ""; a[key] = a[key] "\n" substr($0,2) } 
END { for (key in a) print substr(a[key], 2) > "/path/to/comments/"key }'

the END part needs another substr because every element of the a array starts with an empty line.
Finally, while awk could, of course, subsume grep there does not seem to be a way for it to neatly subsume grep -R.

Good idea. The only caveat is that given a busybox scaled system, you likely don't have 64GB of RAM to store your array. As long as you can accept that you may get an out-of-memory if you have too many matches, you are good to go.

If you are constrainted so (I am not) instead of array accumulating you can store the previous key in a variable, compare and write on change/end. That way you only ever need to hold one file match in memory. It also has the advantage of not needing the second substr() as you are special casing the start of a file anyways.

this will fail if there are more keys than file descriptors. consider busybox awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<4096;++i) a[i] } END{ for(k in a) print k >k }' /dev/null. you should close after each print

Thanks. It was not at all clear and indeed it is slightly confusing that print >  differs from shell >.

> "/path/to/comments/"key is undefined behavior per POSIX, it needs to be > ("/path/to/comments/"key) to work in all awk versions.

Regarding "print > differs from shell >" - I understand why you'd say that but while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done > foo in shell is equivalent to print > "foo" in awk. Both use > and it means the same in both cases so it's not exactly true that "print > differs from shell >" but it is true that print "x" > differs from echo "x" >.

You can avoid the need for substr() in the END section if you populate the array using a[key] = a[key] sep substr($0,2); sep="\n" or a[key] = (key in a ? a[key] "\n" substr($0,2) or similar. By the way, using ORS would be more portable than using "\n" to systems that don't use "\n" as the newline.

$1 = "" would convert all chains of whitespace on the line to individual blank chars, which may not be desirable. It's not obvious why you're doing that.

@edmorton I suspect it's the awk print 1 >f; print 2 >f behaviour vs shell echo 1 >"$f"; echo 2 >"$f" that is non-obvious if one is used to the latter. Much like I always forget the diffference between <<"EOD" and <<'EOD' in Perl vs shell (Perl's seems more logical to me). Re $1="", it seems to come from the linked answer.

Because you want to apply the colon separator only on the read, you should do:
grep -R '^#' * | while IFS=':' read -r file contents; do echo $file-$contents; done

More info: Setting an environment variable before a command in Bash is not working for the second command in a pipe
EDIT: When you want the output in a file do:
output="outputfile"; rm -f $output; grep -R '^#' . | while IFS=':' read -r file contents; do echo "$file-$contents" >>$output; done

the different parts of this statement do:

output="outputfile"   assign the name of the outputfile
rm -f $output       remove this file if it already exists
grep -R '^#' *     search for lines starting with as #
while IFS=':' read -r file contents
read output of previous statement with IFS=':' and assign first column to variable file, and secons column to variable contents
echo $file-$contents >>$output    output these two variables with  -` in between them to the outputfile.


You tried this as a comment, I moved it to chat, flagged as not required why post it as an answer when it barely and inadequately answers half the problem ("It also has the challenge of properly creating and appending to each file.") -- especially when we have my hamfisted but working full solution and an accepted solution which is neat.

OK, I edited my answer, and added some explanation.

P.S. "I moved it to chat": Where is that ?

shellcheck flags some issues with your code

@jhnc: fixed those errors, except for the shebang, which I assume to be bash (and busybox should be a pretty good alternative for that)

$output should also be quoted since the original assignment to it was. To get closer to what seems the desired behavour: dest='/path/to/comments'; grep -R '^#' . | while IFS=: read -r file line; do printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$dest/$file"; done (with restriction that filenames must not contain : which seems to be assumed)

I (personally) never* use a space in pathnames..... They should never have that allowed, because it does not server a (real good) purpose.
